# Adding a directive to an existing element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am attemping to add the required directive to an element, at some point in the future.
In the example, its if the model field is dirty, then make the element required.
I have attempted to just set the required attribute (being a little optimistic)
I am now compiling and linking the element and attempting to replace the old elemenet with the new element.

My element just disappears from the page?
Am I going about this the right way?

```
 app.directive('requiredIfDirty', function ($compile, $timeout) {
                        return {
                            restrict: "A",
                            require: // element must have ng-model attribute.
                            'ngModel',
                            link: // scope = the parent scope
                            // elem = the element the directive is on
                            // attr = a dictionary of attributes on the element
                            // ctrl = the controller for ngModel.
                            function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                                var unsubscribe = scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function (oldValue, newValue) {
                                    if(angular.isUndefined(oldValue)) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    attr.$set("required", true);
                                    $timeout(function () {
                                        var newElement = $compile(elem)(scope);
                                        elem.replaceWith(newElement);
                                    }, 1);
                                    unsubscribe();
                                });
                            }
                        };
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use `Transclusion` in your directive. This would allow you to yank your content, append `required` to it and then compile that. This is a great tutorial that explains the basic concept: [Egghead.io - AngularJS - Transclusion Basics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjrBTjMvruI)

Answer (score -2):

You dont actually need to do that. Angular actually has a directive `ng-required`

see

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.text

You can provide an expression into ng-required on any field that has ng-model and it will add the required validator to it based on the expression evaluating to true.

From the docs

> **ngRequired(optional)** – `{string=}` – Adds required attribute and
>   required validation constraint to the element  when the ngRequired
>   expression evaluates to true. Use ngRequired instead of required when
>   you want to data-bind to the required attribute.

Comment: Its just an example, the question is still how do I dynamically add a directive to an existing element. Thanks for the pointer on required